# How to get Javascript variable value into CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-element

How can I have the `time` variable's contents displayed as the [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) property in my CSS?

JavaScript:

```js
function clock(){
    var d = new Date();
    var hour = d.getHours();
    var min = d.getMinutes();
    var time = hour + ":" + min;
}
```

CSS:

```css
.screen{
    position: absolute;
    height: 75%;
    width: 75%;
    background: #98E8EE;
    top: 11.5%;
    left: 12.5%;
}

.screen::after{
    color: #F9F5F4;
    font-size: 40px;
    content: ;
    font-family: Arial;
    margin-left: 36.5px;
    top: 20px;
    position: relative
}
```

Comment: You can't get value via CSS, but you can manipulate CSS via Javascript

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what you're trying to do? Do you want the time to appear in your CSS?  That wouldn't be very useful for most things.  Are you trying to make the time appear on a web page?  That's a different question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure wether that's the best way to achieve what you want to do, as you could also use a container element and change its content directly:

```js
const screenContentElement = document.getElementById('screen__content');
 
function pad(value) {
  const str = value + '';
  
  return str.length === 2 ? str : '0' + str;
}

function clock(){
  var d = new Date();
  
  return pad(d.getHours())
    + ':' + pad(d.getMinutes())
    + ':' + pad(d.getSeconds());
}

setInterval(() => {
  screenContentElement.innerText = clock();
}, 1000);
```

```css
#screen {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #98E8EE;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

#screen__content {
  color: #F9F5F4;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="screen" class="screen">
  <span id="screen__content"></span>
</div>
```

However, regarding the code you provided, to dynamically change the value of a [`content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content) property in a `CSS` pseudo-element you can use the [`attr()` CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr) together with a [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*):

```js
const screenElement = document.getElementById('screen');
 
function pad(value) {
  const str = value + '';
  
  return str.length === 2 ? str : '0' + str;
}

function clock(){
  var d = new Date();
  
  return pad(d.getHours())
    + ':' + pad(d.getMinutes())
    + ':' + pad(d.getSeconds());
}

setInterval(() => {
  screenElement.dataset.time = clock();
}, 1000);
```

```css
#screen {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #98E8EE;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2rem 0;
}

#screen::before {
  color: #F9F5F4;
  font-size: 40px;
  content: attr(data-time);
}
```

```html
<div id="screen"></div>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use CSS-Variables.

**Can I use:** http://caniuse.com/css-variables/embed

**Docs:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

```js
const updateTime = () => {
  var d = new Date();
  var hour = d.getHours();
  var min = d.getMinutes();
  var second = d.getSeconds();
  var time = `${hour}:${min}:${second}`;
  
  // set CSS variable
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--text`, `'${time}'`);
}

// initial call
updateTime();

// interval to update time
setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
```

```css
:root {
  --text: '----';
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 75%;
  width: 75%;
  background: #98E8EE;
  top: 11.5%;
  left: 12.5%;
}

.container::after {
  content: var(--text);
  color: #F9F5F4;
  font-size: 40px;
  content: ;
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-left: 36.5px;
  top: 20px;
  position: relative
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to add in the content to your element

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the value of time in some css property then you can simple do that using javascript/jquery :

```
$("#SomeId or .SomeCLass").css("PropertyName",time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a javascript value to your CSS (impossible), you can change your CSS value with javascript.

For example, you can use jQuery library and do changes in your html or CSS, according to the value.

Comment: Not impossible, but not very practical. If it's in a style tag javascript can change it... and js has access to stylesheets as well...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're going for, but if you want the value of time to appear on your page, formatted using your css, maybe this?

`document.write( '<p class="screen">' + time + '</p> );`

Or this?

`var timeDiv = document.createElement('div');
timeDiv.classList.add('screen');
document.body.appendChild(timeDiv);`

Just guessing.  Usually CSS defines how things are formatted, so I'm not sure what you're asking.