# How can I use a javascript variable in css?

Tags: javascript, css, variables

I'm trying to generate a grid with Javascript. The user should input a number to establish the size of the grid. If I run the code with a specific number inserted into the javascript code and css it works fine, but as soon as I change the number with a variable and use only the user input it gives me a weird grid.

Here's the code

```js
    const container = document.querySelector(".container");

    //CREATE GRID
    function grid (size) {
        size = prompt("How many squares wide do you want your grid to be?");
        container.style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat(7, 1ft)";
        for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                const square = document.createElement("div");
                square.classList.add("square");
                square.style = "background-color: white; border: 1px solid black";
                container.appendChild(square);
            }
        }
    }
        
    grid(7);
```

```css
    .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px dotted lightgray;

    }
```

```html
<main class="container"/>
```

In this case if I select 7 as the user input it works, but if I replace 7 with "size", which is the variable it doesn't

Comment: You've got a typo error : `container.style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat(" + size + ", 1fr)"` (I've put `size` variable too).

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44445820/how-to-get-javascript-variable-value-into-css/44445899

Comment: Do you know how to use css variables? Those might be the solution to your problem https://eager.io/blog/communicating-between-javascript-and-css-with-css-variables/

Comment: Agreeing with @Chana - that question is very similar, and in particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44445820/how-to-get-javascript-variable-value-into-css/44445899#44446066) would be the most modern solution for your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example solution very similar to your attempt. Notice that I corrected the typo `ft` to `fr` in the code snippet. This uses [back-tick strings (template literals)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for interpolation, but you could also use `+` to join strings together.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

//CREATE GRID
function grid(size) {
  container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${size}, 1fr)`;
  for (let row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    for (let column = 0; column < size; column++) {
      const square = document.createElement("div");
      square.classList.add("square");
      container.appendChild(square);
    }
  }
}

size = prompt("How many squares wide do you want your grid to be?");
grid(size);
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px dotted lightgray;
}

.container>.square {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<main class="container"></main>
```

Here is an example using css variables instead:

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

//CREATE GRID
function grid(size) {
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-size', size);
  for (let row = 0; row < size; row++) {
    for (let column = 0; column < size; column++) {
      const square = document.createElement("div");
      square.classList.add("square");
      container.appendChild(square);
    }
  }
}

size = prompt("How many squares wide do you want your grid to be?");
grid(size);
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px dotted lightgray;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-size), 1fr);
}

.container>.square {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<main class="container"></main>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your var `size` updated from your prompt modal :

Snippet below and possible use : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/xxZxwoM

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

//CREATE GRID
function grid(size) {
  size = prompt("How many squares wide do you want your grid to be?");
  container.style.gridTemplateColumns = "repeat(" + size + ", 1fr)";
  for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
      const square = document.createElement("div");
      square.classList.add("square");
      square.style = "background-color: white; border: 1px solid black";
      square.textContent = i;
      container.appendChild(square);
    
  }
}

grid(7);
```

```css
.container {  
display: grid; 
width: 500px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">  </div>
```

here a version with css variables https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zYrYrOM